# XCode autolayout iOS9 - Styling TextLabel few pixels under top bar and horizontally in the middle

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, ios9, frontend

I've just created a very new iOS application. Haven't developed for iOS since iOS 6. Since then there is iPhone 6 and 6 Plus and the Storyboard autolayout is default.

What I want: I have a default ViewController for now (easy to reproduce, new single view application drops you there) and I just added a TextLabel to the default empty ViewController/View

I've found how to horizontally align this TextLabel (XCode 7.1):

[Aligining horizontally in the middle working on iPhone 4S-5-6-6+ this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqMc2.png)

What I didn't find: how to align this same TextLabel for example n pixels lower than the top bar (the bar including Network status, battery icon, etc.) where

n = 10 times X (X in case of notplus = 2, in case of plus = 3)

If I set to any value the "Vertically in container", the only allowed constraint, it goes out of the screen in case of smaller displays if it's on the top in case of i6. But I want to support smaller display sizes too, and don't want to use just the middle of the iPhone 6/6Plus meanwhile.

Is there an easy solution for this? If not, are there any hard solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this in code by creating an outlet to the constraint and then calculating the distance you want.
You could also try adding a constraint "Center vertically in Superview" and then change the multiplier in the constraint settings. This would enable you to position the textLabel for example 10% below the topBar. This might give you the results you are looking for.